# In Python print iterator variable and index on same line

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, printing, iterator

After the program collects input to create a list of cat names I don't understand how to make the catName list print it's index after the cats name.

Like:
pussy 0
pinky 1

I am learning, so sorry I know it's simple :(

```
catNames = []
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) + 1) +
      ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]  # list concatenation
print('The cat names are:')
#for name in range(len(catNames)):
    #print(name)

for i in range(len(catNames)):  
    print(catNames[I]) #This is the problem - Ineed the print(i) index to print after the [i]
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i in range(len(catNames)):  
    print(str(i), ":", catNames[i])
```

You can do this for print a list in proper sequence.

Comment: Hey, I don't know what happened to my comments that thanked you: But thank you and great job.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `print` statement to this:

```py
print(catNames[i], i)
```

And you don't need this `print(i)` statement anymore.

Comment: Thank you.
I was not clear so your solution was correct. I wanted the list to print down the lines with the index and cat name separated. You did that, This is what I wanted: But I needed the line to drop vertically - Thank all the same ;)

Comment: In that case, you should put your expected out as it is the OP or at least upload a picture of it.

Comment: As you can see in the OP that all the output are in same line, but your expected output was something different, so it makes us confused.

Comment: Anyways, I have updated my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you.
Sorry for the confusion. I assumed from how my script was written it would be evident - My mistake. Your answer was elegantly simple and understandable - I am just so new at this, but still know good code when I see it. Great work!

Comment: I ended up doing this because I like the colon separating the print(catNames[i], " : ", str(I)) Im going to try print(catNames[i], " : ", str(i)) to see if that works.

Comment: Good, happy to help you.